# What is angle value in points along geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, fields-attributes, angles

I generated the points along geometry from Processing toolbox and there is an angle field as default. What does it stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roughly, it refers the azimuth (angle to north) of the line at the location of a point, as in the image.

[image]